# How to get the documents which didn't have parents in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Let's assume I have collection A which is the parent for collection B i.e there is _parent_id field in B which is a "reference" for _id field in collection A.

How can I get the documents in collection B which are orphaned?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `$match` stage immediate after `$lookup` stage, if parent value is [] empty

```
db.B.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "A",
      localField: "_parent_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "parent"
    }
  },
  { $match: { parent: [] } }
])
```